# Maximum-cardinality matching in unbalanced bipartite graphs

Tags: optimization, reference-request, runtime-analysis, bipartite-matching

Let $G = (X+Y, E)$ be a bipartite graph, and suppose we want to find a maximum-cardinality matching in $G$.
The [Hopcroft-Karp algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopcroft%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) runs in time $O(|E|\sqrt{|V|})$, where here $|V| = |X|+|Y|$. So if the graph is unbalanced and $|X|<|Y|$, the run-time is $O(|E|\sqrt{|Y|})$.

Is there an algorithm that attains a better worst-case runtime complexity for the case of an unbalanced bipartite graph, where $|X| \in o(|Y|)$? In particular, if $|X|$ is constant, is it possible to get run-time $O(|E|)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the answer myself. In this paper:

> Lyle Ramshaw, Robert E. Tarjan (2012). "[On minimum-cost assignments in unbalanced bipartite graphs‏](https://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2012/HPL-2012-40R1.pdf)". Technical reports, HP research labs.

in section 5, the authors show that the Hopcroft-Karp algorithm in fact solves the following problem: given an integer $s$, find matchings with $1,\ldots,s$ edges. The run-time is $O(|E|\sqrt{s})$. In particular, if $|X|<|Y|$, we can take $s=|X|$ and the run-time is $O(|E|\sqrt{|X|})$.

Comment: I would suggest this link https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.11244 as an additional note on parameterized matching. It proves square root dependence on many parameters, i.e. $O(|E|\sqrt k)$, for different parameters $k$.